# Laravel 5 load view from outside of the laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am troubling a bit with loading/including files from outside of the laravel installation, I know how to load a view from a directory other than laravel's default like,

```
View::addNamespace('theme', '/path/to/themes/views');
return View::make('theme::view.name');
```

but this is the case to load/include view from outside of the laravel installation. I have a file structure like this,

```
/home
    /laravel-app/resources/views/app.blade.php
    /outside-laravel/subdomain/header.blade.php
                              /footer.blade.php
```

All I want is to include header.blade.php and footer.blade.php file in app.blade.php
This is what I want to achieve in other words in app.blade.php

```
@include("/home/outside-laravel/subdomain/header")
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
@include("/home/outside-laravel/subdomain/footer")
```

Is this really possible?

Any solution other than hardcoding the path using php's inlude/require ?

Comment: Have you tried using `View::addLocation(PATH);`?

Comment: Yes, used that too, does not work.

Answer (score 4):

you have to define a new path for your views folder.
Goto config\View.php
you will find:

```
'paths' => [
        realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
    ],
```

add to it your new view paths:

```
'paths' => [
        realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
        realpath(base_path('your new views path')),

    ],
```